# Struct gets zeroed when function runs out?

Tags: c++, struct, scope

This is probably a noob question, but I don't even know what to google for.

I'm trying to implement a fuse filesystem and am having trouble passing structs, probably stemming from me being inexperienced with C++.

```
static int getStat(std::string path, struct stat *stout)
{
    ...
    struct stat *st = new struct stat();
    lstat(path.c_str(), st);
    // lstat correctly filled st according to gdb
    ...
    stout = st;
    // values are correctly copied to stout according to gdb
}

void something()
{
    struct stat *st = new struct stat(); // this might also be stack allocated by fuse, idk
    getStat("/", st);
    // but st is all zero now !?
}
```

What am I missing? How do I get my data out of the function correctly?

Comment: Not sure if you omitted it or not but do note that `getStat` must return a value otherwise you have UB.

Comment: And there's a potential memory leak as well, if you don't `delete` the structure before allocating and reassigning to `stout`.

Comment: Don't allocate stat on the heap (don't new)! Allocate on the stack and pass the address to lstat.

Comment: Another question: Do you *really* need to allocate the structure dynamically? *Twice?*

Comment: Also note that  using `struct` when you declare a variable is a C-ism and is not needed in C++.

Comment: As for the use-case, the normal way to use the `stat` function and its structure is to use a non-pointer variable and then use the address-of operator. As in `struct stat st; stat(path, &st);` And since you can assign a structure to another structure you don't need the argument to be a pointer either, just a reference.

Comment: @NathanOliver Might be needed here since the OP is using the `stat` *function*. Using `struct` for the structure removes any ambiguities.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Where are they using the `stat` function?  All I see are value initialization calls to the `stat` type

Comment: @NathanOliver Damn, the OP is using the `lstat` function. But doing that the OP still needs headers that declare both a `stat` structure *and* function, creating some ambiguities. Is the compiler required to be able to differentiate between type-names and functions in the global namespace when using a symbol in a declaration? I don't remember.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Aha.  That would do it.  Yes, if there is a stat type and a stat function then you need to decorate the type otherwise it is interpreted as the function.

Answer (score 3):

You have to pass a double pointer to be able to reflect changed pointer in caller function.

So this is the solution

```
static int getStat(std::string path, struct stat **stout)
...
getStat("/", &st);
```

In [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b), function arguments are always passed by value (except references). This means that in the function `getStat()`, `stout` is a copy of the pointer to struct that was passed in the function call.

So, when the new address is assigned to `stout` within the function, this has no effect on the original pointer to struct in `something()` (since `stout` within `getStat()` is only a copy of `st` within `main()`).

Since we are in [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) you are able to use reference as @SomeProgrammerDude suggested.

```
static int getStat(std::string path, struct stat& stout)
struct stat st;
getStat("/", st);
```

Comment: Why use "double pointer" when programming in C++? C++ have pass-by-reference.

Comment: Its just explanation of problem.

Comment: Note that the question is tagged **C++** not C. In C++ you don't need to emulate pass-by-reference as you need in C, since C++ have native references.

Comment: I know and i mentioned that, but i just wanted him to understand why it doesnt work.

Comment: If I change the signature to double pointer the assignment `stout = st;` becomes invalid. My guess is I need to decorate that with additional special characters too, but which ones and where?

Comment: Yes you have to do following `*stout = st;` (Add dereference to stout)

Comment: @Cobra_Fast Are you coming from Java, C# or JavaScript, before starting programming in C++? Because in C++ you don't need to use `new` to create objects. Perhaps you should [read a good beginners book or two](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list)?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I'm coming from PHP and C# mainly. I've been on C adventures before, but nothing major. I would've done this project in C# if it was easily possible. My point of creating some of them with `new` is that I'm collecting them in a `map` and I might end up with quite a lot of them.

Comment: @Cobra_Fast You don't need pointers to store objects in a map (or any other container). Begin with storing plain object instances instead. It usually doesn't matter if you have a large number of objects, there are ways of not having to copy large containers. And copying only a single object is usually quicker than you think. Not using pointers also means less chances of memory leaks, stray pointers, and actually *saves* some memory since you don't need space for the actual pointer (yes, the pointer needs space in memory as well, not only the object).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Okay thanks for the advice, I'll try how far I can get without `new`.